# Populate Virtuals - populate the existing array its referencing .

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to use mongoose's Populate Virtuals to populate the array of values it is referencing?

User Model

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
auth_key: {type: String},
channels: [{
    name: {type: String},
    last_access: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: {type: String, default: false },
    new_messages: {type: Number},
    user_channel_group: {type: String}
}]
}, {
toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
}
});

userSchema.virtual('channels.details', {
ref: 'channel',
localField: 'channels.name',
foreignField: 'name'
});

var user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'user');
```

Channel Model

```
var channelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    members: [{ type: String, required: true }],
    displayName: {type: String},
    type: {type: Number},
    create_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var channel = mongoose.model('channel', channelSchema, 'channel');
```

My query that I am using I want the virtual to present the channel details from each channel alongside the channels a user is subscribed to. so something like this..

```
[{
    "_id": "588a82ff7fe89686fd2210b0",
    "channels": [{
        "details": {
            "_id": "588a80fd7fe89686fd2210a8",
            "name": "channel1",
            "members": []
        },
        "name": "channel1"
    }, {
        "details": {
            "_id": "588a80fd7fe89686fd2210a9",
            "name": "channel2",
            "members": []
        },
        "name": "channel2"
    }],
    "id": "588a82ff7fe89686fd2210b0"
}
    ...
]
```

My Query for this is ..

```
user.find({}).populate('channels.details').exec()
```